# Adding labels to row based on condition of prior/next row

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have sample data like the following in Snowflake. I'd like to assign groupings (without aggregation based on the `grp_start` -> `grp_end` (basically when one `grp_start = 1` I want to assign it a label, and assign each sequential row the same ID until `grp_end` is equal to 1. That would constitute a single grp. Then the next grp should have a different label and follow the same logic.

Note: If a single row is a `grp_start = 1` and `grp_end = 1` I want it to have a single grp label for that row as well, and thus following the pattern.

The data needs to be partitioned by `id` and ordered by `start_time` as well. Please see the below sample data and the mockup of what the desired result is to be. Ideally, I need this to scale to large amounts of data.

Current data:

```
create or replace temporary table grp_test (id char(4), start_time date, grp_start int, grp_end int)
    as select * from values 
    ('0001','2021-01-10',1,0),
    ('0001','2021-01-11',0,0),
    ('0001','2021-01-14',0,1),
    ('0001','2021-07-01',1,1),
    ('0001','2021-09-25',1,0),
    ('0001','2021-09-29',0,1),
    ('0002','2022-11-04',1,0),
    ('0002','2022-11-25',0,1);
    
select * from grp_test;
```

Desired result mockup:

```
create or replace temporary table desired_result (id char(4), start_time date, grp_start int, grp_end int, label int)
    as select * from values 
    ('0001','2021-01-10',1,0,0),
    ('0001','2021-01-11',0,0,0),
    ('0001','2021-01-14',0,1,0),
    ('0001','2021-07-01',1,1,1),
    ('0001','2021-09-25',1,0,2),
    ('0001','2021-09-29',0,1,2),
    ('0002','2022-11-04',1,0,0),
    ('0002','2022-11-25',0,1,0);
    
select * from desired_result;
```

Comment: would it be best, to insert all tables as NULL and then make a query that fit your idea, which  can't follow completely

Comment: it's so funny I have answered this exact question in the last 6 months, but cannot find it. sigh.

Answer (score 2):

so changing the setup data to:

```
create or replace temporary table grp_test as
    select * from values 
    ('0001','2021-01-10'::date,1,0),
    ('0001','2021-01-11'::date,0,0),
    ('0001','2021-01-14'::date,0,1),
    ('0001','2021-01-15'::date,0,0),
    ('0001','2021-07-01'::date,1,1),
    ('0001','2021-09-25'::date,1,0),
    ('0001','2021-09-29'::date,0,1),
    ('0002','2022-11-04'::date,1,0),
    ('0002','2022-11-25'::date,0,1)
    t(id, start_time, grp_start, grp_end);
```

We can use two [CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_true_event)'s, this allows us to know we we are outside the end, but before a start, and thus can alter the label to null.

```
select d.*
    ,CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(grp_start=1) over (partition by id order by start_time) as s_e
    ,CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(grp_end=1) over (partition by id order by start_time) as e_e
    ,iff(s_e != e_e OR grp_end = 1, s_e, null) as label
from grp_test as d
order by 1,2;
```

| ID | START_TIME | GRP_START | GRP_END | S_E | E_E | LABEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2021-01-10 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0001 | 2021-01-11 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0001 | 2021-01-14 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0001 | 2021-01-15 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 0001 | 2021-07-01 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 0001 | 2021-09-25 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 0001 | 2021-09-29 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 0002 | 2022-11-04 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0002 | 2022-11-25 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

If you don't actually care about label rows after an end, but before the next start, you can just use a single CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT

```
select d.*
    ,CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(grp_start=1) over (partition by id order by start_time) as label
from grp_test as d
order by 1,2;
```

| ID | START_TIME | GRP_START | GRP_END | LABEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2021-01-10 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0001 | 2021-01-11 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0001 | 2021-01-14 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0001 | 2021-01-15 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0001 | 2021-07-01 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 0001 | 2021-09-25 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 0001 | 2021-09-29 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 0002 | 2022-11-04 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0002 | 2022-11-25 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses two nested window functions, max and dense_rank.  Snowflake (as well as most other DBMSs) doesn't allow you to nest two window functions, so we'll process the first one in a subquery and the second one in the query itself.

The key to this method is to assign a common date-value to all members of the group, in this case the start date of the group, then dense_rank will give a 1 to all the records tied for first place, a 2 to the next group, etc.  So we want the max(Start_Time) of the records with grp_start=1 at or before this time for every row in grp_test.

```
max(Case When grp_start=1 Then Start_Time End)
  Over (Partition By ID Order By Start_Time
        Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as grp_start_time
```

So put it all together with

```
Select ID, Start_Time, Grp_Start, Grp_End,
    dense_rank(grp_start_time) Over (Partition By ID) as label
From (
    Select ID, Start_Time, Grp_Start, Grp_End,
      max(Case When grp_start=1 Then Start_Time End)
        Over (Partition By ID Order By Start_Time
        Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as grp_start_time
    From grp_test
)
Order by ID,Start_Time
```

**METHOD 2**
You can simplify this considerably if you are certain grp_start must only contain zeros and ones.  This one simply creates a running sum of grp_start:

```
Select ID, Start_Time, Grp_Start, Grp_End,
    sum(Grp_Start) Over (Partition  By ID Order By Start_Time 
            Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as label
Order by ID,Start_Time
```